# postgresql column with optional result from subquery

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table with a three columns: id, title, entity_type and depending on value of entity_type I would like to retrieve one value from other table using subquery. If I write my query as:

```
Select current_table.id,
(SELECT status FROM other_table join current_table on other_table.entity_id = current_table.id where entity_type = "some_type") as status
 from current_table
```

I will get back only records where entity_type = "some_type" but I want to retrieve all data from current_table and make subquery result optional and have null in that column for other entity_type.
In reality query is a lot bigger with multiple joins already that's why I don't want to use Left Join, to not brake whole query.
How my goal can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand you your goal already *is* achieved, because `status` will be NULL if no row is found in the subquery.

You *really* should refactor your query to use an outer join, even if that is painful, because it will be so much better from a performance point of view. Of course, if the query returns only a few rows, it does not matter.